# Spring bean get initialized twice by xml and component-scan

Tags: java, spring

I have created few singleton bean in spring. I added log inside constructor. I could see log is getting printed twice.

```
@Component
public class User{

        public User() {
         System.out.println(" Bean got initialized"+this);
       }  
        private Integer userid;

        private String username;

        //getter and setter

    }
```

I have defined bean in XML  and configured auto-scan.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />
<bean id="user" class="com.demo.User"/>
```

Since I have initialized bean in context xml and package scan, bean is getting initialized twice. After removing @Component from class, I am seeing only once log.

Please confirm my understanding is correct or not?

Comment: Annotations were introduced in Spring, so that we do not  have to configure xml properties exolicitly. When you are using @Component, that is doing the job of creating a bean of the User class. So when you use@Component, and also create a bean "user" explicitly, it will obviously create two instances

Answer (score 0):

That's correct; the component scan will pick it up, and then you explicitly create another copy.

Answer (score 0):

`@Component` annotation was introduced in spring 2.5 in order to get rid of XML bean definition by using classpath scanning. if the class is annotated with `@Component`,  it will auto detected in the classpath scanning and an instance will be created(instantiated). Since @Component does the job for creating the bean, you do not have to declare the bean in XML. So remove the XML bean declaration. so it will not create duplicate objects.

Note: if you do the annotation based bean declaration with @Component, you do not need to use XML based declaration as you have done. If you are doing the XML based bean declaration, you do not need to do the annotation based bean declaration. So make sure that you declare only one of these options. not with both.